# How to get object from firebase?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Hello I'm new in firebase. I have this object and tried some versions of code but still getting undefined. 
How can I get an object and refer to its lastname etc?
Or can someone guide me or give me a good tutorial for firebase?

[image: this image represents all]

Comment: there is no best tutorial than the one they provide: https://www.firebase.com/tutorial/. great docs.

Comment: Can you use a code snippet rather than a screenshot? They're much easier to read. Even better would be if you could create a example in JSBin :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference's value will only be available at `.$value` if you expect it to be a Primitive (`Number`, `String` or `Boolean`). Otherwise, the reference returned by `$firebaseObject` will be mutated to remain synchronized with the remote data at that reference.

Try doing `console.log(obj);` instead.

See: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebaseobject-value

Comment: So obj.lastname  should work in this scenario ?:) gonna test it asap when back to home

Comment: It should work as you suggest. However, if it was a primitive value at that reference, you would need to have accessed it via the `$value` property.

Comment: @Alex if the answer is correct, I would encourage you to accept it! Cheers.

Comment: I went to parse.com ;D

Answer (score 0):

```
yourFireBaseRefHere.on("value", function(snapshot) {

     var yourData = snapshot.val();

}
```

An easy way of getting data from firebase.